# JAXB2 generates getters/setters with primitive types for optional attributes

Tags: java, jaxb2, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin, jaxb2-basics

We are using jaxb2 to generate Java code from xml schema definitions for some external data. The project is quite old and used the maven-jaxb-plugin 1.1.1. We want to update to jaxb2-maven-plugin which will also use jaxb2, but we found some differences in the generated code. Specifically, we have attributes in the form of

```
    <xsd:attribute name="num" type="xsd:int" use="optional">
```

which are mapped to `Integer` fields in the generated code.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "num")
protected Integer num;
```

However, jaxb2 generates getters and setters with primitive type instead of nullable types:

```
public int getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(int value) {
    this.num = value;
}

public boolean isSetNum() {
    return (this.num!= null);
}

public void unsetNum() {
    this.num = null;
}
```

However, our current code assumes that `getNum` returns a nullable boxed type and also tests this in unit tests which fail with a null pointer exception.

Is there a way to generate getters/setters with nullable types for optional attributes? The xsd files are provided from an external vendor so I would prefer to not modify them. We do not set `optionalProperty` in `<globalBindings>`, so the value is the default `wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution to my own question. In addition to `optionalProperty` in `globalBindings`, there is the option `generateIsSetMethod` which controls if methods like `isSetNum` shall be generated or not. If this is enabled, primitive types such as `int` will be used instead of `Integer`.